# Load an R object after an assigning its name

Tags: r, assign

I am trying to find a way to save an object after an assign.
I based my example on this topic that helps: [How to save R data object that has been created using assign()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574711/how-to-save-r-data-object-that-has-been-created-using-assign)

The object is correctly saved when I check in the folder but impossible to open it with R. When I try to open it, I have the regular question whether I want to load it, then nothing appears in my environment (with and without number at the beginning of its name ...).

Do you have an idea ?

Here is my example:

```
res <- 12345
sku = 'sku_a'
index = 1
# index = 'hello'
# create variable based on string combination
# assign variable value with res

assign(paste0(index,'_arima_',sku), res) 

paste0(index,'_arima_',sku) %>% save(file = paste0(index,'_arima_',sku,'.RData'))
paste0(index,'_arima_',sku) %>% save(file = paste0('_arima_',sku,'.RData'))
paste0(index,'_arima_',sku) %>% save(file = paste0(index,'_arima_',sku,'.RData'))
```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Charlotte

Comment: You should show us the code you actually used.  I suspect the problem is with your `assign()`, which we can't see.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I dit try and it still did not work. So I removed it. But I will put it back for more clarity. 
In any case it is still not working, with or without assign()